# How do I get the upper half of the Volume id in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, volume

[This link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntfslabel.8.html) at Ubuntu says "The option --new-half-serial only changes the upper part of  the serial  number,  keeping the lower part which is used by Windows unchanged."

That suggests that the upper half of the Volume Id exists on the disk, is there any way to get at this in Windows? (GetVolumeInformation only returns the lower half). Ubuntu shows the entire 64-bit value with `blkid`.

Notes:

"This is not the volume UUID used by Windows to locate files which have been moved to another volume."

This refers to the Volume UUID, not the Volume Id I am talking about here. The Volume UUID is of the form: `\\.\Volume{7E899CB7-0079-11E1-BC4E-002219F6E9D9}`

Comment: Volume Id's and other associated information are stored in the registry. Are you trying to get the volume id from an open file handle or a path?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Either one, the problem is that any source I find (either programmatic or utility) only provides the lower 32 bits, not the upper 32. E.g. `vol C:` has this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a look at the

```
NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER
```

structure, and the DeviceIO Command:

```
FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA
```

And the function `DeviceIoControl()`.  I think you will find what you are looking for in there.  The first member of the NFTS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER is defined as a LARGE_INTEGER, which is just a typedef to:

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    };
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

Let me know if that helps at all...